# how to customize the header of qtablewidget

Tags: qt

by default ,the header of qtablewidget has the some column  numbers  with the tabwidget,
so ,if the tablewidget has 2 columns, the header also has 2 columns,

now I want to implement the header by myself, 
I want to create a header only has one column, and add some button on it , how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

Put qtablewidget and pushbutton inside qvboxlayout. Set item spacing for layout to 0. Hide horizontal header for qtablewidget and you should get this:

[image]

If you are doing this in code, use this:

```
QVBoxLayout *verticalLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
verticalLayout->setSpacing(0);

QPushButton *pushButton = new QPushButton("Table header");
verticalLayout->addWidget(pushButton);

QTableWidget *tableWidget = new QTableWidget;
tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setVisible(false);
verticalLayout->addWidget(tableWidget);
```

Comment: +1 Simple and effective.  You can also add an arrow to the `QPushButton`'s label, and when pressed performs sorting on the contents and inverts the arrow - mimicking a 'real' header column.