# Is there a way to add button into header cell of PyQt tablewidget?

Tags: python, pyqt

You can add any widget into table cell, using setCellWidget function. But what about adding widget into header?

Comment: well, there is a setHorizontalHeaderItem (self, int column, QTableWidgetItem item) function which takes QTableWIdgetItem as an argument but you can only place text there

Comment: the only thing that comes to my mind is something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11689568/4464653). You can push this one step further for multiple columns by changing the button width within the repaint event of the table. Haven't found something on creating a custom QTableWidgetItem,

Comment: I see, imitating headers is probably the easiest way

Comment: I show how to put a checkbox into a header [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30938728/1994235) which might at least show you the direction to go in even if it doesn't directly do what you want.